# categorical generalizations of familiar objects

Tags: abstract-algebra, soft-question, category-theory, big-list

A couple of days ago I've learned that you can define trace in a very abstract setting.

Namely, suppose $F\colon A\to B$ is a functor between two categories. Suppose $E,G\colon B\to A$ are two functors, that are adjoint to $F$, such that $E$ is left adjoint and $G$ is right adjoint. Suppose moreover that $\nu\colon G\to E$ is a natural transformation. Then having this data $\forall x,y\in A$ you can define the trace map $$Tr\colon Hom(F(x),F(y))\to Hom(x,y)$$ for any $f\in Hom(F(x),F(y))$ to be the composition $$x\to GF(x)\to EF(x)\to EF(y)\to y,$$ where the first map is given by the adjunction unit $id_A\to GF$, second map is given by $\nu$, the third map is given by $E(f)$ and the last map is given by the adjunction counit $EF\to id_A$.

If we take $A=B=Vect_k$, $F=-\otimes V$ and $G=E=-\otimes V^*$ for some finite dimension vector space $V$ over $k$, and take $x=y=k$, then this construction gives the usual trace of a linear map.

From the top of my head I remembered a couple of more examples.

For example, if $C$ is a category, the Bernstein center of $C$ is defined to be $Z(C)=End(id_C)$, the (commutative monoid) of endomorphism of the identity functor. If the category $C$ is additive, then $Z(C)$ is a commutative ring. If we take $C$ to be the category of modules over some ring $R$, then $Z(C)$ is isomorphic to the center of $R$.

Another one, you can talk about open, closed subfunctors on the category of commutative rings into $Sets$. If your functors are representable, then you get the usual definition of open or closed subschemes.

So my question is: **What are other nice examples of such categorical generalizations that you now?**

Comment: If $C$ is a category, its center is a priori just a monoid (and, as it turns out, a commutative monoid). To get a ring you need $C$ to be $\text{Ab}$-enriched.

Comment: Yes, you are right! Thank you. I have corrected it.

Comment: Also, this is a very broad question. Nearly everything in category theory generalizes something familiar. Can you be more specific?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan You are right. The point is that the fact, that disjoint union of sets can be generalized by a certain colimit is not that surprising if you know a little bit of category theory. Neither is the fact, that free algebra on a set is just an adjoint functor. But examples with trace or with center seem to be more surprizing (for me). So I would like to learn some more such unexpected examples.

Comment: I agree, the question is WAY too broad. Today's mathematics is full of "categorical generalizations" ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are a few examples:

**Kahler differentials**

Everything I say here can be found in the [nLab page on Kahler differentials](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/K%C3%A4hler+differential). Notice that for a commutative ring $A$, the category of $A$-modules is equivalent to the category $\operatorname{Ab}(\mathsf{cRing}/A)$ of abelian group objects in the category commutative rings over $A$. One associates to an $A$-module $E$ the "square-zero extension" $A\oplus E$ with multiplication $(a,x)(b,y)=(ab,a y+b x)$. There has a natural forgetful functor 
$\operatorname{Ab}(\mathsf{cRing}/A)\to \mathsf{cRing}/A$, and the formation of Kahler differentials forms a left-adjoint to this. That is, 
$$
  \hom_{\mathsf{cRing}/A}(B,A\oplus E)
     = \operatorname{Der}_A(B,E) 
    = \hom_{A\text{-}\mathsf{mod}}(\Omega_{B/A}^1,E)
    = \hom_{\operatorname{Ab}(\mathsf{cRing}/A)}(A\oplus \Omega_{B/A}^1,A\oplus E) 
$$

This can be generalized to an arbitrary category. Following nLab, we replace $\mathsf{cRing}$ with $\mathsf{AffSch}$, and define, for any category $\mathsf{C}$, the *tangent category* of $\mathsf{C}$ to be the category of pairs $(x,A)$, where $x$ is an object of $\mathsf{C}$ and $A$ is an abelian group object in $\operatorname{Ab}(\mathsf{C}^\circ/x)$. Here I write $\mathsf{C}^\circ$ for the opposite category of $\mathsf{C}$. There is a forgetful functor from $T\mathsf{C}$ to the "arrow category" $\mathsf{C}^\to=\operatorname{Nat}(\bullet\to\bullet,\mathsf{C})$ that sends $(x,A)$ to the structure morphism $x\to A$. If we write $F:(T\mathsf{C})^\circ\to \mathsf{C}^\to$ for this functor, then we can define $\Omega^1$ to be the left-adjoint (if it exists) to $F$, i.e. 
$$
  \hom_{x\backslash \mathsf{C}}(A,y) = \hom_{\operatorname{Ab}(\mathsf{C}^\circ/x)}(\Omega_{y/x}^1,A)
$$
for $(x,A)$ in $T\mathsf{C}$ and $x\to y$ in $\mathsf{C}$.

This definition of Kahler differentials is "correct" in many contexts - simplicial commutative rings, smooth rings, ...

**Lie algebras**

This perspective on Lie algebras originated (I think) in SGA 3, exposé II. Let $S$ be a scheme and consider $\mathsf{Sch}_S$, the category of schemes over $S$. One starts by defining a functor from $S_\mathsf{qc}$, the category of quasi-coherent $\mathcal{O}_S$-modules, to schemes over $S$ by sending $\mathcal{M}$ to $I_S(\mathcal{M})=\operatorname{Spec}(\mathcal{O}_S\oplus\mathcal{M})$. (Astute readers will notice that this is exactly the previous construction). Now let $X$ be a presheaf on $\mathsf{Sch}_S$. One define, for each $\mathcal{M}$ in $S_\mathsf{qc}$, the *tangent bundle* of $X$ relative to $\mathcal{M}$ to be the functor 
$$
  T_{X/S}(\mathcal{M}) = \underline{\hom}_S(I_S(\mathcal{M}),X):Y\mapsto \hom_S(I_S(\mathcal{M})\times Y,X)
$$
(See the section on exponentials for an explanation of $\underline{\hom}$). If $X$ is represented by an actual scheme (which I'll call $X$), then $T_{X/S}=T_{X/S}(\mathcal{O}_S)$ is represented by $\mathbb{V}(\Omega_{X/S}^1)=\operatorname{Spec}(\operatorname{Sym}(\Omega_{X/S}^1))$.

If $X$ comes with an $S$-valued point (e.g. if $X=G$ is a group-valued functor with identity section $e:S\to X$) then the Lie algebra of $G$ is defined for any quasi-coherent $\mathcal{O}_S$-module $\mathcal{M}$: 
$$
  \operatorname{Lie}(G,\mathcal{M}) \subset T_{G/S}(\mathcal{M})
$$

where $\operatorname{Lie}(G,\mathcal{M})(Y)$ is the set of $f\in T_{G/S}(\mathcal{M})(Y)=\hom_S(I_S(\mathcal{M})\times Y,G)$ such that the composite $Y\to I_S(0)\times Y = S\times Y = Y\xrightarrow{f} G$ is $Y\to S\xrightarrow{e} G$. (Note that I'm writing $X\times Y$ for $X\times_S Y$.) In other words, $\operatorname{Lie}(G,\mathcal{M})$ is the fiber product $S\times_G T_{G/S}(\mathcal{M})$. (In case it isn't clear, I'm being a little excessively loose in identifying schemes with their functor of points.)

If we let $\operatorname{Lie}(G) = \operatorname{Lie}(G,\mathcal{O}_S)$, then there is a general "adjoint action" $\operatorname{ad}:G\to \underline{\operatorname{Aut}}(\operatorname{Lie}(G))$, where $\underline{\operatorname{Aut}}$ is defined much like $\underline{\hom}$.

**Subobject classifiers**

This is much less complicated, and can be found in Mac Lane and Moerdijk's book *Sheaves in Geometry and Logic*. For $\mathsf{C}$ a category, a *subobject* of $x$ is an equivalence class of monomorphisms $u\to x$, where $u\to x$ and $v\to x$ are equivalent if they both factor through each other. One says that $\mathsf{C}$ has a *subobject classifier* if the functor that sends $x$ to $\operatorname{Sub}_\mathsf{C}(x)$, the class of subobjects of $x$, is represented by some $\Omega$ in $\mathsf{C}$. (In particular, if $\mathsf{C}$ has a subobject classifier, each object has a set, not a proper class, of subobjects.)

For $\mathsf{Set}$, the subobject classifier is $\Omega=\{0,1\}$, and the representability of $\operatorname{Sub}_\mathsf{C}$ is essentially the fact that subsets can be identified with their characteristic functions. However, more interesting categories (like sheaves on a site) also have subobject classifiers.

**Exponentials**

Further details here can also be found in Mac Lane and Moerdijk. One says that a category $\mathsf{C}$ with products *has exponentials* if for all $x$ in $\mathsf{C}$, the functor $y\mapsto x\times y$ has a left-adjoint. One denotes this adjoint by $(-)^x$, i.e. 
$$
  \hom(x\times y,z)=\hom(y,z^x)
$$
For $\mathsf{Set}$, $x^y$ is the set of functions from $y$ to $x$, and the adjunction expresses the fact that functions $f:y\times x\to z$ can be identified with their transpose: $y\mapsto (x\mapsto f(x,y))$. Once again, more interesting categories (like sheaves on a site) also have exponentials. In fact, if $F$ and $G$ are sheaves on a site $\mathcal{C}$, then the sheaf exponential $F^G$ is defined by 
$$
  (F^G)(c)=\hom(G\times c,F)
$$
where once again I identify $c$ with $\hom(-,c)$. Note that $F^G$ is sometimes written $\underline{\hom}(F,G)$. It's definition is not ad hoc either. One has (using the Yoneda lemma and the adjunction between exponentials and cartesian product)
$$
  (F^G)(c) = \hom(c,F^G)=\hom(G\times c,F)
$$

Answer (score 6):

A nice example is the notion of matrix. The most general setting (that I know of!) in which we can usefully think about matrices is in a category with finite [biproducts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biproduct). Common examples include abelian categories like categories of modules but there are even more general examples than this. See [this blog post](http://qchu.wordpress.com/2012/09/14/a-meditation-on-semiadditive-categories/) for some examples and more details. One gets back the prototypical case of finite-dimensional vector spaces over a field $k$ by decomposing every such vector space as a biproduct of copies of $k$.

Comment: What, if I may ask, is the connection between matrices as described in that blog post and the following definition? Suppose we're working in a concrete category. Let $(X,\Gamma)$ denote a free object and $Y$ any other object. Then a matrix $M : (X,\Gamma) \rightarrow Y$ is just an ordered triple $(f,(X,\Gamma),Y)$ where $f$ is a function $\Gamma \rightarrow UY$. Similarly, a matrix $M : (X,\Gamma) \rightarrow (Y,\Delta)$ is just an ordered triple $(f,(X,\Gamma),(Y,\Delta))$ where $f$ is just a function $\Gamma \rightarrow UY$.

Comment: (I've been assuming that this is the correct generalization of the term "matrix" for a while, putting aside that we don't bother ordering $\Gamma$ or $\Delta$).

Comment: @user: I don't understand your notation. What are $X$ and $\Gamma$ in the notation $(X, \Gamma)$? What is $U$? In what sense is this a generalization of matrices?

Comment: Ah sorry. $U$ is the forgetful functor of the concrete category, assume the codomain is $\mathrm{Set}$. $\Gamma$ is meant to denote a subset of $UX,$ and $(X,\Gamma)$ is a free object equipped with a distinguished basis. If $(X,\Gamma)$ is a "based" object, a mapping $f : \Gamma \rightarrow UY$ gives rise to a morphism $f : X \rightarrow Y$ via the universal property of free objects. Hence a bit like a matrix. To see the connection more concretely, an $n \times 3$ real-valued matrix $[\tilde{y}_0,\tilde{y}_1, \tilde{y_2}]$ is a bit like a mapping $f : \{e_0,e_1,e_2\} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n.$

Comment: Where by "based" object I mean a free object equipped with a distinguished basis. Also by $e_i$ I mean the $i$th canonical basis vector for $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: @user: okay. This doesn't seem like a useful definition in a concrete category where most objects aren't free, but the point is that picking a basis of a finite-dimensional vector space in the sense of picking an identification with a free object is equivalent to picking a biproduct decomposition (using the fact that the free functor preserves colimits). But I think the notion of matrix I give above is more useful, e.g. because it accommodates naturally the case of block matrices, triangular matrix rings, etc.

Comment: Okay, thanks. $\;\!$

Comment: @user: you also lose something crucial if you work in a category where coproducts aren't products, namely it's natural to want to decompose the source of a morphism as a coproduct but to decompose the target of a morphism as a product, and if these don't agree then it's unclear how to describe composition without more effort. Whereas in the biproduct case composition is literally matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps one of the most obvious examples is that of the [nerve of a category](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nerve_%28category_theory%29) (and so also the classifying space of a category.

The nerve $N(C)$ of a category $C$ is a simplicial set which in some sense encodes the topological structure of a category. The $0$-simplicies of $N(C)$ are the objects of $C$ and the set of $k$-simplicies $N_k(C)$ of the nerve are the towers of composable arrows of length $k$.

The face maps $d_i\colon N_k(C)\rightarrow N_{k-1}(C)$ are given by formally composing the tower at the $i$th position (or forgetting the arrows at the ends if $i=0$ or $k$). So for instance if $$\alpha=(f_0,f_1,f_2)\in N_4(C)$$ then $d_0(\alpha)=(f_1,f_2)$ and $d_1(\alpha)=(f_1\circ f_0,f_2)$.

The degeneracy maps $s_i\colon N_k(C)\rightarrow N_{k+1}(C)$ are given by formally inserting an identity arrow before $f_{i}$ (or after $f_{k-2}$ in the case $i=k-1$).

The classifying space $BC$ of $C$ is then the geometric realisation of the nerve $N(C)$. This generalises the usual construction of the classifying space $BG$ of a group $G$ by forming the usual category $C_G$ with one object whose arrows are the elements of $G$ with composition given by group multiplication. We get $$BG\cong BC_G.$$

The concept of a nerve of a category also generalises the concept of a nerve of an open covering of a topological space. If $X$ is topological space with open cover $\mathcal{A}=\{U_{\lambda}\}$ we denote by $N(\mathcal{A})$ the [nerve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nerve_of_an_open_covering) of the covering $\mathcal{A}$. We also form the category (in this case a poset) $C_{\mathcal{A}}$ whose objects are the $U_{\lambda}$ and an arrow $U_{\lambda}\rightarrow U_{\lambda'}$ exists if $U_{\lambda}$ is a subset of $U_{\lambda'}$. We have $$N(\mathcal{A})=N(C_{\mathcal{A}}).$$